# 'Looping' JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have the below script.

```
function slideShow1(){
    document.getElementById('dynimg').src="Other/noctis.jpg";
    var timer1 = setTimeout(slideShow2(),5000);
}

function slideShow2(){
    document.getElementById('dynimg').src="Other/retriever.jpg";
    var timer2 = setTimeout(slideShow3(),5000);
}

function slideShow3(){
    document.getElementById('dynimg').src="Other/miningop2.jpg";
    var timer3 = setTimeout(slideShow1(),5000);
}
```

It's crude, I know... And it's also not working. The idea is for each function to trigger the next after a given period and therefore creating a slideshow where and img is changed repeatedly. I am trying to use body onload="slideShow1()"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those parentheses are causing your function to be executed immediately.

```
setTimeout(slideShow2(), 5000);
```

As such, you think you're passing your *function* to `setTimeout` but you're actually *executing* your function and passing its *return value* (`undefined` in this case).

So, your function gets called immediately and `setTimout` has nothing to execute five seconds later.

Just remove the parentheses:

```
function slideShow1(){
    document.getElementById('dynimg').src = "Other/noctis.jpg";
    setTimeout(slideShow2, 5000);
}

function slideShow2(){
    document.getElementById('dynimg').src = "Other/retriever.jpg";
    setTimeout(slideShow3, 5000);
}

function slideShow3(){
    document.getElementById('dynimg').src = "Other/miningop2.jpg";
    setTimeout(slideShow1, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Another way to say it: you're passing "_the result of executing the function_" rather than passing "_a reference to a function that will get executed later_".

Comment: So the object returned by the function will be the one that would get called the `call()` method on.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't parse a function with an argument into setTimeout?

Comment: @canon - Sorry, I probably wasn't clear. Lets say I want my setImgSrc(newSrc){} function to be called by a setTimeout function.. does that mean I can't because setImgSrc requires an arguement?

Comment: @canon Please don't suggest that. It's non-standard and doesn't work in IE. You even provided the link to the MDN docs that say this...